# What tense should I use for case studies?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

I am writing case studies and stuck with this:

> The client ***was*** from the IT field and ...

The problem with this is should I use 'was' or 'is'.

Now, the client's status as on today is also the same, but when I am writing this case study, it should mention the client's status when we had this project on the floor. In other words, case studies are always in past because you're describing something that happened then. But, as far as the status or background is concerned it is the fact even today.

So, should we use past or present tense in such cases?

Comment: Similarly, the client *had/has* an expertise in iOS technology! Good question.

Comment: If the case study describes a project which is still ongoing, use the present. If the project is no longer in progress, use the past.

Comment: Mr Dant. That looks like a good answer, why is it only a comment?

Comment: Laziness, I'm afraid, and the sense that as soon as I spend 20 minutes framing a cogent answer replete with references and _bons mots,_ @StoneyB will follow up with an answer which renders mine inane by comparison.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Check Maulik's comment. The project was in past, but the status mentioned is still the truth like the client 'had' an expertise in iOS technology is not the truth because the client still 'has' it. On the other hand, if I write has, it talks about the present status but the project was in past.

Comment: This is easily solved. "The client was, and still is, involved in the design of widgets."

Comment: I have never come across such sentence in case-studies while this is grammatically true, I need a better sentence. @P.E.Dant

Comment: If you imagine that this construction is unusual or inappropriate, I can only say that you are mistaken. It is a perfectly plausible way to deal with this conundrum in English. However, in most such cases, the past would be used without any concern for the current status of the subject of the case study.

Comment: FWIW, if you don't let the facts force your tenses, but instead let your thoughts guide your tense usage, you'll find it much easier to deal with tenses.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a situation where you called on Tom at his home. The following day, you can say to a mutual acquaintance

> Tom **was** at home yesterday

In this context, it is neutral about where Tom is now. He could be still at home: he could be somewhere else.

Now suppose that, when you were at Tom's house, you asked him where he came from, and he replied

> I **am** from London.

When you tell your mutual acquaintance, you say to him

> Tom said he **was** from London. - *reported speech - backshifted*
>   Tom **is** from London - direct statement

You can use **is** because Tom is definitely **still** from London.

Similarly, when you interview your client, you might get these answers:

> My name is Tom
>   I am 34 years old
>   I work at XYZ bank
>   My background is in IT
>   I work in accounts

When you are writing up your report a few months later, you would be obliged to say

> His name is Tom - still true
>   He was 34 years old - at the time of the interview
>   He worked at XYZ bank - at the time of the interview
>   His background is in IT - still true
>   He worked in accounts - at the time of the interview

I am not suggesting that you should always switch between **present** and **past** like this: it is just an example that shows how you can express these ideas precisely if required.

If it's not necessary to be precise and you have multiple items of information, it's probably best to stick to whichever is the most common of **present** or **past**: the context will usually be enough to avoid misunderstanding.

If precision is important, it depends exactly what you mean by "from the IT field". If it means "His training is in IT", then it's still true, so you should use **is**. If it means "He is currently working in IT", you should use **was**.